# Using the Organizational Browser with two User Profile Services

Tags: user-profile-service, organization-browser

I have a SharePoint 2010 Server configured with two User Profile Services.

The default UPS has 100 profiles configured.

The second UPS has 20 profiles configured.

A user in the second UPS has a manager from the default UPS.

When using the Organizational Browser I can see the manager and his direct reports who are also in the default UPS but not any of the direct reports who are in the second UPS.

Is this a known limitation or are there some additional configuration steps I need to complete?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Each User Profile Service functions separately. Only the web applications associated with the User Profile Proxy will use the associated UPA.

The behavior you are seeing is by design.

Generally, an organization has one UPA.